# Can I run both versions of Madden 22 (current & next Gen) with MVP edition

Tags: madden-22

I have some friends who play Madden 22 on Xbox One. As I have the Series X, I bought the MVP edition as it said it included both the Xbox one and Series S/X versions, however, only one game is installing, with nothing else in the queue.

I looked online and there was talk of dual entitlement when I googled it which made it sound like it was a free upgrade to next gen. Which is strange as it advertised both versions on the purchase screen.

So can I run both versions so I can play with my friends on current gen consoles and have my own game on next gen? Or have I just spent extra money for no reason? If I do have access to both, how do I launch the current gen version to play with friends?

Comment: So to be clear, you have an Xbox Series X/S, bought this game for it, and want to run the Xbox One version on your Series X/S so you can play with your friends?

Comment: @TimmyJim yes, that is correct!